# mouse wheel isn't scrolling in tmux

Tags: scroll, ubuntu-11.10, tmux

It scrolls ok in vim but not in tmux.

I followed suggestions like adding

```
set -g history-limit 1000
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
setw -g mode-mouse on
set-window-option -g mode-mouse on
```

to `.tmux.conf` but none of them helped

All I get, regardless of the above is history command scrolling.

Comment: You're issuing commands at shell prompt, therefore set is most likely being understood a bash's builtin (cf. help set) while setw doesn't exist so your system tries to suggest the closest match it knows.  The set and setw (shorthand for set-window-option) are tmux's command and you can use them at tmux's command prompt, prompted by ctrl-B, or as an argument to tmux command itself as in "tmux setw -g mode-mouse on"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Correct command is:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
```

You can also add it to your ~/.tmux.conf

Comment: You need to type it in tmux command prompt (type CTRL-b and :).. Read the manual.

Comment: When I do this, I just get gibberish characters appearing at the prompt (any terminal prompt, e.g. bash prompt or IPython prompt, etc.) What else needs to happen for mode-mouse to do naive scrolling?

Comment: Its just `set -g mouse on` for me. (version `2.1-1`)

Comment: As noted in the [tmux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Mouse_scrolling),

> This interferes with selection buffer copying and pasting. To copy/paste to/from the selection buffer hold the shift key.

Comment: This doesn't work on new tmux versions so it should be updated with correct information or removed as correct answer.

Answer (score 22):

Just to link two relevant answers together:

> Why does `tmux set -g mouse-mode on` no longer work?

As pointed out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336609/2375855), the option got renamed since **tmux version 2.1** to:

```
tmux set -g mouse on
```

To find your local tmux version, just run `tmux -V`.

Answer (score 1):

```
set -g mouse on
```

Just like this if it's going in your ~/.tmux.conf