# "tmux set -g mouse-mode on" not scrolling

Tags: tmux

To allow scrolling a tmux pane with a mouse, I put the following in my `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set -g mouse-mode on
```

However, nothing changes. When I scroll, it still scrolls outside of tmux. Why is this?

Comment: `mode-mouse` in the old version

Answer (score 719, accepted):

So this option has been renamed in version 2.1 (18 October 2015)

From the [changelog](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/2.1/CHANGES#L6L13):

```
 Mouse-mode has been rewritten.  There's now no longer options for:
    - mouse-resize-pane
    - mouse-select-pane
    - mouse-select-window
    - mode-mouse

  Instead there is just one option:  'mouse' which turns on mouse support
```

So this is what I'm using now in my `.tmux.conf` file

```
set -g mouse on
```

Comment: @Sukima - The changelog can be found [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES).

Comment: I'm confused, as I have version `2.1` installed on two different systems, both Ubuntu 16.04 (one hasn't been upgraded in a long time.) However, though both report version `2.1` when running `tmux -V`, I have to use the `mouse` option on one system and the old names on the other. Anyone know why this could be the case?

Comment: While this is working for Mac, it with `set -g mouse on`, it will break the ability to select text in Mac's terminal. I have to specifically do `set -g mouse off` to select text

Comment: @Wins press shift before selecting or pasting

Comment: @mdekkers it doesn't work. pressing shift while selecting text in terminal doesn't even select the text.

Comment: @Wins try `alt`, that's what I use for iTerm2

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux/510310#510310

Comment: @Wins use `fn` key as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35841352/828885.

Answer (score 83):

As @Graham42 noted, mouse option has changed in version 2.1. Scrolling now requires for you to enter copy mode first. To enable scrolling almost identical to how it was before 2.1 add following to your `.tmux.conf`.

```
set-option -g mouse on

# make scrolling with wheels work
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
```

This will enable scrolling on hover over a pane and you will be able to scroll that pane line by line.

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tmux-users/TRwPgEOVqho/Ck_oth_SDgAJ

Comment: This seems to work, however I can't select text in panes anymore. Anyone else also having this issue?

Comment: @will.fiset: yes, this is expected as mentioned in the [FAQs](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#i-want-to-use-the-mouse-to-select-panes-but-the-terminal-to-copy-how). hold the `shift`-key while you try to mark text, this should work in most terminals.

Answer (score 79):

Just a quick heads-up to anyone else who is losing their mind right now:

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/310f0a960ca64fa3809545badc629c0c166c6cd2/CHANGES#L12

So that's just

```
:setw -g mouse
```

Comment: Or if you want it always on, simply add `set -g mouse` in `~/.tmux.conf`. Though note that this will make copying/pasting text into the terminal via the mouse more difficult (I'm sure there's a way - I just haven't looked it up myself).

Comment: @J.M.Janzen Many terminals keep mouse events for themselves if you hold Shift while clicking. The mouse event won't be passed to tmux (or vim, for that matter) and text will be selected natively by the terminal.

Answer (score 43):

this should work:

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
```

then resource then config file

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

or kill the server

Comment: I used set -g mouse on and the source-file command you gave, worked perfectly.

Comment: `.tmux.conf:1: invalid option: mode-mouse`

Answer (score 28):

Paste here in ~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g mouse on
```

and run on terminal

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for
byobu --version
byobu version 5.73
tmux 2.5

while the suggestions above didn't.

Answer (score 18):

This line:

```
set -g mouse-mode on
```

in your `~/.tmux.conf` file won't work.

For one thing, the proper setting is `mode-mouse`, not `mouse-mode`.

Second, it only works on older versions of `tmux` (pre-version 2; you can run `tmux -V` to see what version you have, but you can also run `man tmux` to see if `mode-mouse` is a supported option).

And third, technically `man tmux` says to use the `mode-mouse` option with `setw` (`set-window-option`) and not with `set` (`set-option`), although I've seen it work with `set` (as well as `setw`).

---

These lines should work:

If your version of `tmux` is recent enough (that is, if `tmux -V` shows version 2 or newer), you can put this line in your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-option -g mouse on
```

But if you use an older version of `tmux`, put these lines in your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-window-option -g mode-mouse on

set-option -g mouse-resize-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-window on
```

Again, if you're not absolutely sure which line(s) to put in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, run `man tmux` and search for `mouse-mode`, `mouse-resize-pane`, `mouse-select-pane`, and/or `mouse-select-window`.  If you find them, then use those options (the ones for the older version of `tmux`).

Putting these lines in will allow you to use the mouse scroll wheel, it will allow you click on various panes to activate them, and it will allow you to resize panes just by clicking-and-dragging on their splitter separator.

You can also copy-and-paste using your mouse.  However, you may notice that copying-and-pasting with your mouse may not work like it normally does on your console.  To work around this, I've noticed that holding down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key while using your mouse's copy/paste abilities makes them work normally again.  (On MacOS, <kbd>fn</kbd> seems to work for me better than <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.)  Or you can learn `tmux`'s approach to copy-and-pasting (which I do recommend).

---

A note on using `tmux`'s native ability to copy/select/paste:

Personally, I feel that the `vi` keys make more sense to me than the default `emacs` keys (for example, it feels more natural to exit *selection mode* with `vi` mode's <kbd>ENTER</kbd> than with `emacs` mode's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>), so I have this in my `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
# For vi-like keys in copy/paste/selection mode:
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

However, I've noticed that on older versions on `tmux`, this line won't work, *unless* I've *also* included the line:

```
set-window-option -g mode-mouse on
```

---

**Good to know:**  Occasionally, when you're using the mouse's scroll wheel, you'll discover that your pane/screen appears to be frozen or locked up (it won't respond to keyboard input), and it's not clear what to do to unlock it.

It's not locked up.  You're likely in `tmux`'s selection mode.  To get out of it, try one of these:

- Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  (Will likely work in `vi` mode.)
- Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.  (Will likely work in `emacs` mode.)
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.  (Will likely work in `emacs` mode.)
- Hit <kbd>META</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.  (Will likely work in `emacs` mode.)
- Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  (Will likely work in `emacs` mode.)
- Hit <kbd>q</kbd>.  (Will likely work in `vi` mode, and may work in `emacs` mode as well.)

Ultimately, you can try hitting:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>     <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>     <kbd>q</kbd>

Chances are, that will put you back in the normal mode where your keyboard is responsive again.

---

Using the mouse with `vim`:

I've discovered that putting this line in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
:set mouse=a
```

seems to work well with `tmux`, better than this line:

```
:set mouse=r
```

I can't really explain the difference; if you're a `vim` user, try them out and see which setting works best for you.

---

If you need to test out these `tmux` options, you may find yourself editing your `~/.tmux.conf` file, exiting `tmux`, and then restarting `tmux`.  This can become a tedious process, so if you want some work-arounds, here are some options:

*Option1:*  After editing (and saving) your `~/.tmux.conf` file, run this command (while in `tmux`):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This will immediately apply the new settings in your `~/.tmux.conf` file into your current `tmux` session, without the need to restart `tmux`.

*Option 2:*  If you're in a `tmux` session, you can turn on/off options temporarily just for that session by running commands like these at the Unix shell prompt:

`tmux set-option -g mouse on`

`tmux set-window-option -g mode-keys vi`

*Option 3:*  You can also temporarily turn on/off options in a `tmux` session with:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> `:set-option -g mouse on` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> `:set-window-option -g mode-keys vi` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

Good luck, and have fun using `tmux` !

Answer (score 17):

As @Graham42 said, from version 2.1 mouse options has been renamed but you can use the mouse with any version of tmux adding this to your ~/.tmux.conf:

**Bash** shells:

```
is_pre_2_1="[[ $(tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2) < 2.1 ]] && echo true || echo false"
if-shell "$is_pre_2_1" "setw -g mode-mouse on; set -g mouse-resize-pane on;\
      set -g mouse-select-pane on; set -g mouse-select-window on" "set -g mouse on"
```

**Sh** (Bourne shell) shells:

```
is_pre_2_1="tmux -V | cut -d' ' -f2 | awk '{print ($0 < 2.1) ? "true" : "false"}'"
if-shell "$is_pre_2_1" "setw -g mode-mouse on; set -g mouse-resize-pane on;\
      set -g mouse-select-pane on; set -g mouse-select-window on" "set -g mouse on"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the idea behind this answer is pure genius! ...and could also help for `style`-options resp. [`fg`-, `bg`- and `attr`-abolition in tmux 2.9](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-translate--fg--bg-and--attr-options-into--style-options). but it does not work because at least my shell refuses to compare floating-point numbers... and if your localization uses something else than `.` as a floating-point, you must also work around this issue.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy What's the output of `tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2` in your shell?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy I've improved my answer. Test the new version!

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco 1) thanks for such a quick reaction and also reworking your answer! **||** 2) the `tmux -V | cut -d ' ' -f2`-part is fine, works correctly on a bunch of machines (tested with Debian, CentOS etc.) and gives `1.8`, `2.1` or whatever tmux version it is as output.

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco i reworked your answer a little bit and changed `set -g mode-mouse on` because [it is/was a window-option](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.7/tmux.1#mode-mouse) and should rather be `setw -g mode-mouse on` or `set -gw mode-mouse on`. ...but well, it seems that some versions of tmux accept both variants.

Comment: anyhow, it still does not work! :-( my tmux version 2.1 still complains about an `unknown option: mode-mouse`... so my guess is, line 1 is fine now, but line 2 is still not workinkg. - i'm not 100% sure what's the problem and if it is a tmux- or a bash-thing, because i'm completely new to tmux and never seen such an if-case.

Comment: Note: on ubuntu 19.10, the version is tmux 2.9a. So I used `tmux -V | sed -E 's/tmux ([0-9.]*).*$/\\1/;'` to parse it more robustly.

Comment: Note: that at least for me on Ubuntu 18.04, even if `/bin/sh` is Bash, I need the **Sh** syntax, probably because [Bash enters POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco sorry for partly butchering your commands back then! i've corrected my mistakes and updated them to even work with the alphanumerical versioning (via `sed`). **||** i also added an other variant and some further explanation... perhaps the `echo`s at the bash variant finally confused me completely. PS: the nesting and quoting is a nightmare! ;-)

Comment: Hello @DJCrashdummy Thanks for your review! I cannot test it since tmux is very recent in all my machines. I suggest you to send it as a new answer and refer to mine so that other people will be able to test it and will find it useful! Moreover, did u see my last answer :) ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61938005/3589567

Answer (score 13):

You can still using the devil logic of setting options depending on your current Tmux version: see my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332679/3589567).

But since Tmux v1.7, `set-option` adds "-q" to silence errors and not print out anything (see [changelog](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES)). 
I recommend to use this feature, it's more readable and easily expandable.

Add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# from v2.1
set -gq mouse on
# before v2.1
set -gq mode-mouse on
set -gq mouse-resize-pane on
set -gq mouse-select-pane on
set -gq mouse-select-window on
```

Restar tmux or `source-file` your new `.tmux.conf`

---

Side note: I'm open to remove my old answer if people prefer this one

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It works on my computer.

```
set -g mouse on
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone actually losing it because they already have `set -g mouse on`, check your terminal settings to see if "Enable mouse reporting" is on.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and then set mouse. `-g` is not needed anymore.

Comment: Mouse doesn't do anything after ctrl b

Comment: push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and then :set mouse