# How to copy to mac when using mac terminal -> ssh into ubuntu -> tmux

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, copy-paste, tmux

I am currently on MacOS Ventura. I typically use the Mac Terminal utility to ssh into an Ubuntu 20.04 machine. Once I've ssh'd into the Ubuntu machine, I'd like to use tmux (3.0a) to manage multiple panes/windows, but I'm having trouble copying from the tmux session to my mac.

I have installed xclip on the Ubuntu machine. and my `.tmux.conf` file looks like:

```
# Mouse support (e.g., click on different panes)
set -g mouse on

# Extend the history (line limit) in each pane
set-option -g history-limit 50000

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind P paste-buffer
bind -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind -T copy-mode-vi r send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'
```

I got these commands from [this blog](https://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting-ubuntu/) and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287432/how-to-copy-to-system-clipboard-from-tmux-output-after-mouse-selection/70305647#70305647). While the vi key bindings work fine within tmux, the buffer contents do not percolate to my mac's copy buffer.

I'd appreciate any help with this!

Comment: xclip on remote side linux cannot manipulate local side macos' clipboard.

Comment: Good point, I now have xclip installed on both remote linux & on local mac but does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get tmux copy mode to copy into my local clipboard, but I did find a workaround that allows me to copy from a tmux terminal, which solves my problem (if not my question).

I was able to successfully copy/paste from my mac into/from a ssh tmux window with the commands fn+cmd+c (select text with mouse while holding the keys down, then release keys and press enter) for copy and fn+cmd+v for paste. It's a bit clunky and I'm not sure why this works, but it does.

Answer (score -1):

I use this in my config on macOS AND linux. Works in both.

```
tmux_conf_copy_to_os_clipboard=true

bind -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-selection-and-cancel
```

Comment: Since I am using tmux on the remote linux machine (not the mac), I'm unclear how putting this on my mac would help. But I added it to both configs regardless, but it did not work.