# tmux and mouse mode with ssh

Tags: ssh, conda, mouse, tmux

I am taking ssh connection to linux where is tmux 3.3 (installed from conda). Mouse mode is not working, I want to use mouse to select panel (split window) or scroll terminal . I have tried help from here, but none of them didn't help:
[tmux mouse mode doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832199/tmux-set-g-mouse-mode-on-doesnt-work)